# Strapi: Problem uploading images to strapi, image does not render

Tags: javascript, file-upload, content-management-system, strapi

### Problem

I would like to know if you can help identify the issue related to uploading an image to the `thumb` field belonging to the content-type `Directory`.

The image image does not render once it is in the strapi panel, it only shows the name.

```js
const getFileSize = (filePath) => {
  return statSync(filePath)["size"]; // statSync from `fs-extra` library
};


 strapi.service("api::directory.directory").create({
      data: {},
      files: {
        thumb: {
          path: `${imagesDir}/Crab-1-1-scaled.jpg`,
          name: "Crab-1-1-scaled.jpeg",
          type: mime.lookup(`${imagesDir}/Crab-1-1-scaled.jpg`), // mime from `mime-types` library
          size: getFileSize(`${imagesDir}/Crab-1-1-scaled.jpg`),
        },
      },
    });
```

### console.log

`size` is always zero

```js
{
  files: {
    thumb: {
      path: 'src/scripts/Directory/images/Crab-1-1-scaled.jpg',
      name: 'Crab-1-1-scaled.jpeg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      size: 0
    }
  }
}
```

### output

When uploading the data the image is not rendered, it only shows the name of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I do in Strapi 4 is this: I first use the built-in upload plugin, which returns an id of the uploaded file. I then use the id to create/update my entity (*Directory* in your case).

Here is a working code snippet you can use:

```
    const filename = originalFile.split('.')[0]
    const ext = originalFile.split('.').pop()
    const rootDir = process.cwd();
    const filePath = `${rootDir}/public/uploads/${originalFile}` // the file is moved here already - the upload plugin will not upload anything, only reference the existing file.

    const entity = {
      path: filePath,
      name: originalFile,
      hash: `${filename}${ext}`,
      mime: mime.lookup(filePath),
      provider: 'local',
      ext: ext,
      type: mime.lookup(filePath),
      size: fs.statSync(filePath)["size"],
    };

    const localUpload = await strapi.plugin('upload').service('upload').upload({
      files: entity,
      data: {}
    });
    console.log("LOCAL UPLOAD done", localUpload[0].id)
```